# Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: instruction changed the balance of a read-only account

Tags: send-transaction

I wrote a function in typescript by using `solana/web3.js`. Sometimes, I received this error. I simply implement code following [the doc of solana](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/javascript-reference). I realized if I use `sendRawTransaction`, it will be better result, the failure percentage is quite lower than `sendTransaction`.

```
const amount = this.convertSOL2LAMPORT(request.amount).toNumber()
const transaction = new solanaWeb3.Transaction().add(
  solanaWeb3.SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: signerKeyPair.publicKey,
    toPubkey: new solanaWeb3.PublicKey(request.to),
    lamports: amount,
  }),
)

const result = await this.provider.sendTransaction(
  transaction,
  [signerKeyPair],
  {
    /**
     * * Base on retry transaction fact
     * * https://solanacookbook.com/guides/retrying-transactions.html#facts
     */
    maxRetries: 5,
  },
)
```

P/s: I'm using third party api (which is Quicknode for testnet and GetBlock for mainnet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a unoffical solution that send multiple transaction with the same hashTx. Many error returned but the success result responsed together. I thought this is potent

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Frompubkey and topubkey should be wallet address and you also need to give recent blockhash and fee payer to all the transaction object

Comment: I still dont understand. In following guide, the from_pub_key with be the fee payer, it's very clear in sample which solana team provided. But are there any difference between `sendTransaction` and `sendRawTransaction` will raise this error?

Comment: @LeeToan Yes, there is a difference. Post your sendRawTransaction code in the original question. You said only sometimes you get the error, what are the conditions? Are you trying to send multiple rapidly?